# Can not find selenium WebElement twice

Tags: java, selenium

Working with selenium and InternetExplorer 11, I can navigate around this site.

I got a method that finds an input box on the page then inputs text. It works the first time, but when I go to another page it says that element does not exist and the page just refreshes randomly.

I a m just using a simple wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Enter Name')]")));
WebElement nameField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Enter Name')]"));
```

It crashes and says the element can not be found during the wait.

I am not sure if this is just site specific or if I am doing something wrong.

If anyone has any idea I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: "It works the first time, but when I go to another page it says that element does not exist": You "go to another page", in that  page it also have the same element with the same xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As you mentioned `when I go to another page` the entire HTML DOM gets changed and now if you try to locate or use `findElement()` with a previously found `id`/`name`/`css`/`xpath` Selenium will fail to do that.

So when we are on a new page we have to search for the element again using the current `id`/`name`/`css`/`xpath` in-order to use `click()` or `sendKeys()` methods.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.